# ADB Retrieve list of Class Tests from APK

Tags: android, adb

I have been tasked with automating a manual test. The manual test had a file of the classes and tests that it referenced when it wanted to run.

**Instead of manually looking at the file, is there was a way to retrieve the list of Classes and corresponding Tests via ADB so I can generate my own list(s)?**

I do not have access to the source code of the APK.

Example Steps:

```
adb install -r -g Apples.apk
adb shell pm list instrumentation
instrumentation:com.exampleApples/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner (target=com.exampleApples)
```

If I wanted to run the full set of tests under a certain class:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.exampleApples.GrannySmithTests com.exampleApples/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

If I wanted to run a specific Test from a Class:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.exampleApples.GrannySmithTests#bite com.exampleApples/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `adb` command, but there is [dex-member-list](https://github.com/JakeWharton/dex-member-list), `dex-method-list` and `dex-field-list` to list the class members. With [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten) or [FernFlower](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine) it should also be possible to get the names.

Answer (score 0):

Just do that.

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e log true -e class com.exampleApples.GrannySmithTests com.hike.chat.stickers.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

This will return you all the classes under *com.exampleApples.GrannySmithTests*.